# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list function () {

Tags: javascript

i have spent about 2 hours trying to find the "missing (" but i found nothing.
i have even print my script and checked and averything seems to be ok.
this error is showing on firebug console.

i am completely new on javascript so maybe i am ignoring something logical.
any help will be appreciated.

thanks,
mj

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Totalizar</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#Calculate").click(
                // mueve el valor al campo de cantidad
                function () {
                    var total = 0;
                    var total_qty = 0;
                    $("input[name=f_qty]").each(
                        function () {
                            var quantity = $(this).val();
                            var productId = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_prod_id]").val();
                            if (quantity != '') {
                                var price = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_unit_price]").val();
                                var prodtotal = (quantity * price);
                                total = total + prodtotal;
                                total_qty = total_qty + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    $('#printHere').html(decimalizer(total));
                    $('#printHereqty').html(total_qty);
                }
            );
            // funcion para formatear el rotulo de resultado a 2 decimales
            function decimalizer(input) {
                var test1 = 0;
                var test2 = 0;
                input = Math.round(input * 100);
                if (input / 100 == Math.round(input / 100)) {
                    test1 = 1;
                } else if (input / 10 == Math.round(input / 10)) {
                    test2 = 1;
                }
                if (test1 == 1 && test2 == 0) {
                    return (input / 100 + ".00");
                } else if (test1 == 0 && test2 == 1) {
                    return (input / 100 + "0");
                } else {
                    return (input / 100);
                }
            }
            //---------------------------------------Inicia Proceso de aplicacion del pedido----------------------------------------
            // Aplica el Pedido
            $("#Save").click(
                // ----- Agregar los productos a la collection
                function () {
                    $("input[name=f_qty]").each(
                        function () {
                            var quantity = $(this).val();
                            var productId = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_prod_id]").val();
                            if (quantity != '') {
                                $("#P1_CANTIDAD_PEDIDO").val(quantity);
                                $("#P1_PRODUCT_ID").val(productId);
                                apex.server.process("ADD_PRODUCTS", {
                                    pageItems: "#P1_CANTIDAD_PEDIDO,#P1_PRODUCT_ID"
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                //---------- Fin de agregar los productos a la Collection -------------
                function () {
                    apex.server.process("SAVE", {
                        pageItems: "#P1_CODIGO_CLIENTE,#P1_TIPO_CLIENTE"
                    });
                    var total = 0;
                    var total_qty = 0;
                    alert('Orden Creada');
                    // Poner en 0 las cantidades digitadas
                    $("input[name=f_qty]").each(
                        function () {
                            var quantity = $(this).val();
                            if (quantity != '') {
                                $(this).val('');
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    //
                    $('#printHere').html((total));
                    $('#printHereqty').html(total_qty);
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="totals"></div>
    <p>
        <strong>NETO DEL PEDIDO: 
<span id="printHere"></span>
</strong>
    </p>

    <p>
        <strong>TOTAL PRODUCTOS: 
<span id="printHereqty"></span>
</strong>
    </p>
    <p align="center" style="clear: both;">
        <button type="button" style="font-weight: bold;background-color:lightgray;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;margin-top:0%;margin-bottom:0%" id="Calculate">Actualizar</button>
    </p>
    <p align="left" style="clear: both;">
        <button type="button" style="font-weight: bold;background-color:lightgray;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;margin-top:5%;margin-bottom:5%" id="Save">Procesar Orden</button>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try running through http://jshint.com before posting here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#Calculate").click(
        // mueve el valor al campo de cantidad
        function () {
            var total = 0;
            var total_qty = 0;
            $("input[name=f_qty]").each(
                function () {
                    var quantity = $(this).val();
                    var productId = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_prod_id]").val();
                    if (quantity !== '') {
                        var price = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_unit_price]").val();
                        var prodtotal = (quantity * price);
                        total = total + prodtotal;
                        total_qty = total_qty + 1;
                    }
                }
            );
            $('#printHere').html(decimalizer(total));
            $('#printHereqty').html(total_qty);
        }
    );
    // funcion para formatear el rotulo de resultado a 2 decimales
    function decimalizer(input) {
        var test1 = 0;
        var test2 = 0;
        input = Math.round(input * 100);
        if (input / 100 == Math.round(input / 100)) {
            test1 = 1;
        } else if (input / 10 == Math.round(input / 10)) {
            test2 = 1;
        }
        if (test1 == 1 && test2 == 0) {
            return (input / 100 + ".00");
        } else if (test1 == 0 && test2 == 1) {
            return (input / 100 + "0");
        } else {
            return (input / 100);
        }
    }
    //---------------------------------------Inicia Proceso de aplicacion del pedido----------------------------------------
    // Aplica el Pedido
    $("#Save").click(
        // ----- Agregar los productos a la collection
        function () {
            $("input[name=f_qty]").each(
                function () {
                    var quantity = $(this).val();
                    var productId = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_prod_id]").val();
                    if (quantity !== '') {
                        $("#P1_CANTIDAD_PEDIDO").val(quantity);
                        $("#P1_PRODUCT_ID").val(productId);
                        apex.server.process("ADD_PRODUCTS", {
                            pageItems: "#P1_CANTIDAD_PEDIDO,#P1_PRODUCT_ID"
                        });
                    }
                }
            );
            functionName(); 
        });

        //---------- Fin de agregar los productos a la Collection -------------
        function functionName () {
            apex.server.process("SAVE", {
                pageItems: "#P1_CODIGO_CLIENTE,#P1_TIPO_CLIENTE"
            });
            var total = 0;
            var total_qty = 0;
            alert('Orden Creada');
            // Poner en 0 las cantidades digitadas
            $("input[name=f_qty]").each(
                function () {
                    var quantity = $(this).val();
                    if (quantity !== '') {
                        $(this).val('');
                    }
                }
            );
            //
            $('#printHere').html((total));
            $('#printHereqty').html(total_qty);
        }

});
```

You have forgot to close the "**$("#Save").click**" event

Comment: Now you have a stray, nameless function after the `.click()` that will throw a SyntaxError.

Comment: well, maybe i am confuse. i need to execute the two functions inside the "$("#Save").click" event. what is worng in my code ? thanks

Comment: rman, it worked !!, can you give me a little explanation about what was wrong ? thanks

Comment: now when it says : SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
function () {

Comment: @Siberia i have already update the answer for this error, please review again.. just copy paste the code... now.. it will work for you..

Comment: @Siberia Please find "functionName" in the code.. and give appropriate function name to this function